# Which is the best approach to create rounded and cool styled buttons with the 80% of the width of the screen?

Tags: android, layout, button, view

I'm developing a Android app.

I have a menu screen on my app, which must have some buttons. I need for the buttons to have always a width of 80% of the width of the screen and these buttons must be cool styled, with rounded sides and some style on them, not bad looking buttons. Also these buttons must contain the text I want to put on them.

I tried to do this creating png buttons and scaling them on android (by java code) but this way is a bad way.

I want to learn a better way to do this, **for example, creating views directly with java code and overwriting onDraw method**. Which is the best approach for achieve my needs?

**code examples are welcome**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the built-in buttons with a color filter to give them a different color. This keeps their cool shape and shading. Use android:weight in the layout xml to make them occupy 80% of the screen width.

```
Button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x64034C8C,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

This example uses 8 hex digits to define the color. The first two digits specify the transparency, while the others define the RGB values of the color.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might benefit from looking into **9 patch mechanism**. There are many tutorials on how to do so.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: Pableras84 is telling that he don't want to use PNG's for the buttons, he wants to use other approach. Draw 9-patch generates PNG's, so it's not a solution for him.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use 9-patches, but still want to create styled buttons you could use Shapes.
[This blog post](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/drawing-shapes-in-android/) may help you.